# 'Journey Email Send By Day Report' (CSV file) cant be added into data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, journeybuilder, sql, automationstudio

I am saving the ‘Journey  Email Send Summary by Day’ as a CSV file into FTP. Which looks like this..
[image]

Then I am importing it using Automation Studio using ‘import activity’.
My target DE has these fields - Date, Total_Sent, Total_Delivered.
The import is successful.But when I check the target Data Extension  it shows something like this,

[image]

My goal is to just import the 2nd row values  (Example: 543, 543)

How to fix this?

I want to store the “journey  email send by day” in Data extension with only the 3 fields. But not able to solve.
Is there any work around for this issue??

OR
Is there any SQL query using which I can extract "journey  email send report by day" of only these 3 fields  ??

Comment: Did you validate that it is mapping correctly in the import activity?

Comment: @Gortonington Yes it is mapped according to the header name

Comment: Did you try going into the manual version and verifying that they actually match. I have seen times when OOTB reports in SFMC will add quotes around the column names - making it so they do not match automatically to the fields in the DE.

Comment: @gortonington, the data comes into Data extension, But as I showed in the attached image in answer, that I just need the first row of data. which does not get populated into data extension. Only the 2nd row with empty values gets populated.